# vsdファイルのデフォルトアプリケーションを切り替えたい

Tags: c#, windows, visio

【質問】
2つのバージョンのVisioが混在しているPCでvsdファイルのデフォルトアプリケーションを切り替える方法はありますか?
現在作っているアプリケーションでVisio 2013を使用したいのですが、ユーザーはVisio 2007を使う必要があるため、2つのバージョンが混在しています。

【現在の状況】
現在使用している環境は以下の通りです。
2つのバージョンのVisioをインストールしています。

Windows 10 Pro 64bit

- Visio 2013 32bit
- Visio 2007 SP3 32bit

現在、vsdファイルのデフォルトアプリケーションはVisio 2013になっています。

- アイコンからVisio 2013であるとわかります。
- vsdファイルをダブルクリックして開くと、Visio 2013で開きます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

vsdファイルをダブルクリックするとVisio 2013で開きますが、以下のダイアリーが必ず表示されます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

【アプリケーションのソースコード】
interopを使っています。

```
var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application() { Visible = false };
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 出来るかどうか＆問題無いかどうか不明ですが、この記事 [Windows のファイル拡張子の関連付け](https://qiita.com/TsuneoNakanishi/items/5f0248c82bf073cf2868) の内容で調べて、`.vsd`の起動コマンドを`Visio2007`のプログラムに変えてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。今回の環境はPythonがインストールされていないことを前提とさせてください。使えるのはバッチファイルのみです…　ちなみにレジストリComputer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.vsdも色々ためしましたが、効果はなかったです…

Comment: 紹介先の記事にPythonの話題が書かれているのはたまたまであり、`assoc`と`ftype`の動作にPythonは不要ですよ。まあ質問のことが出来ない/出来るが方法を知っている人が居ない/方法を知っている人がこの質問を見ていない、といったあたりのいずれかの状況でしょうか。